# converting textfield value to characters array

Tags: java, arrays, string, text, textfield

I need to be able to set the input of the textfield to an array of characters. I've tried getting the text from the textfield and making it a string to then convert that string to characters, however this does not work.

I get an error on this line: `String string = TextField.getText();`
The error states that I: `Cannot make a static reference to a non static method getText() from the type textComponent`

I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong so any help would be much appreciated.

```
package lab4;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import lab3.FontSize;
import lab3.Calculator.event;

public class Scrolling extends JFrame{


JLabel label;
JTextField Textfield;
JPanel panel;
public String string;

public static void main (String[]args){

    Scrolling scroller = new Scrolling();
    scroller.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    scroller.setTitle("Marquee scroller");
    scroller.setSize(1500,750);
    scroller.setVisible(true);
    scroller.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
}

public Scrolling() {

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    panel1.setSize(1500, 300);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter text and press return");
    label.setVisible(true);
    label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel1.add(label);


    JTextField TextField = new JTextField();
    TextField.setVisible(true);
    TextField.setFont(TextField.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
    TextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

    panel1.add(TextField);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,10));


    Label[] labelArray = new Label[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
            labelArray[i] = new Label("");
            labelArray[i].setBackground(Color.white);
            labelArray[i].setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
            labelArray[i].setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
            labelArray[i].setText("1");
            panel2.add(labelArray[i]);
        }

        add(panel2);
        add(panel1);

        event e = new event();
        TextField.addActionListener(e);
}



public class event implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String string = TextField.getText();
        char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();

    }
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

JVM is confusing your object name with class, in `Java` is **highly discouraged to start variable or object names with `uppercase`**

You must refer you instance of TextField, not the class itself, rename:

```
JTextField TextField = new JTextField();
```

to

```
JTextField mTextField = new JTextField();
//         ^note lowercase to start variable name
```

Remember to rename all occurences in your code, then you will do:

```
String string = mTextField.getText();
```

Comment: Cheers! I found out the initial issue, it was a simple mistake and I just happened to initialise the JTextField as "Textfield" and not "TextField".